Dialog Example on page https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/dialogs is not working
I have slash command with dialog configured to open dialog in my chat app, It was working till yesterday, suddenly it's not working now. It throws "Server error occurred. Please try again." and closes dialogue. On the network tab I can see a CORS error as below
https://dynamiteintegration-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/invoke_dialog?alt=protojson&key=AIzaSyB0RaagJhe9JF2mKDpMml645yslHfLI8iA' from origin 'https://chat.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
I tried using the Apps Script example from documentation page https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/dialogs as it is. Event that doesn't show contents inside dialog box.

I have an app that works using google chat API and I'm having this exact same issue ONLY when a dialog is opened, started happening today. There's no traceback on any of the logs from GCP services. This must be Google's fault.

Seconding this, it appears that within the past 24 hours the CORS issue appeared on any Chat request which includes opening of a Dialog card. This functionality was working fine yesterday and my code was not changed, so it appears that this is some kind of issue on the Google side.
